# How to apply security on a folder using web.config file?

Tags: asp.net, security, web-config, folder-security

I have folder on which i want to apply security like the current user who is using the site, can access that folder but if he is not currently logged in then he cannot see the content of that folder or files of that folder. I know we can do it in web.config file but i dont know how. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at the location node? Or putting a web.config in the folder itself with an authorization node.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I have understood the question...

You can use location elements in the web.config file, there is a lot of information on the web about that - this gives you a start:  [HOW TO: Control Authorization Permissions in an ASP.NET Application](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871)

You basically have elements like this:

```
<configuration>
    <location path="subdir1">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users ="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

That is saying allow all users to the subdir1, you have a deny element too - information here: [authorization Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d82143t%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Create a separate `web.config` file with permission inside the folder that you need security.

Also have a look at this article about [Control Authorization Permissions in an ASP.NET Application](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871)

eg.

```
 <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <deny users="?" />                
            </authorization>
</system.web>
```