# User Access and displaying fields based on user type

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls

I have a website written in ASP.NET using VB.  Users log into this site.  There are many different types of users based on the department.  Depending on the type of user, we need to have certain things displayed for some user types and other things display for other user types.  I would like to have a system of displaying things based on that user type but not have a bunch of IF statements if possible.  Currently we have a folder for each user type that has pages that are using a master page for that type.  Those pages in come cases use user controls but in other cases do not.  When they do not use user controls, we are getting duplication of fields across many of the pages.  This is making maintenance and enhancements time consuming.  The bad part is, if I were to put for example 'Contact Information' in a user control, not all of the contact information would be displayed for each type of user.  Some types of users have somethings and other types of users have other things.

Please keep in mind, one of the main problems we have is, this website is already very large so I cannot completely redesign it at this time.

Does anyone have any strategies or resources I can look at to develop a really great and organized way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

While you can put a web.config in each folder to control access to each folder, this does not solve your issue with the UserControl.  You will have to use **IF** statements in that control. But that doesn't seem like a big deal. It's just one control.

[Controling security with web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810127/how-to-apply-security-on-a-folder-using-web-config-file)

Comment: Thank you for your response.  There are a bunch of controls that have issues of users needing to see something depending on the user type.  There would be if statements in all of those controls also.

Comment: I dont see any other way. Sorry I couldn't help.